# Adding lists of files from two directories

Tags: perl

I'm using the syntax:

```
 my @inFiles = </var/test1/*.*>;
```

to get the files in a directory into an array.

How do I get the files from a second directory into the same array?

Pseudo-code: (I know this isn't real)

```
my @inFiles += </var/test2/*.*>;
```

Note: I can't depend on the name of the directory being similar so I can't do something like:

```
my @inFiles = </var/test*/*.*>;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) to add elements to the end of an array

```
push @inFiles, </var/test2/*.*>;
```

Comment: Alternative : `my @inFiles = ( </var/test1/*.*>, </var/test2/*.*> );`

Comment: Yep, could also just do `my @inFiles = </var/test1/*.* /var/test2/*.*>;`, but teaching about array functions feels more important in this case.

Comment: @Miller What's the best to to chomp each entry in the array?

Answer (score 1):

As [Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23300414/368630) explained, you can use [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) or [unshift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unshift.html) to add items to an array. See [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org) for complete Perl documentation.

However, when working with directories, your best bet is to use [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) to parse your directories:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use function qw(say);
use File::Find;

# Directories you want to use
my @directories = qw(/directory/first /directory/second);

my @files;  # Files in those directories you want

find ( 
    sub {
        return unless -f;   #Files only...
        push @files, $File::Find::name;   # Name of the file you found
    }, @directories
);
```

When you finish, all of the files in both directories will be in `@files`. This doesn't just include the files directly under the directory, but also subdirectories.